# How do I get ".is" to work in older versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, hover

I'm not getting ".is" to work. It's working great in IE9, firefox and other modern browsers but not IE8 or IE7

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').click(function () {                   
                if (!$('.myDiv').is(":hover")) {
                    alert("outside of blue div");
                }
        });
</script>

<div class="myDiv" style="width:150px; height:150px; background:blue">&nbsp;</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Or look here http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/

How do I get it to work in IE8 and older?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(document).click` instead of `$('body').click`.  Sometimes the `<body>` tag doesn't take up the full screen height/width, so you may be clicking outside the `<body>` tag.

Also, instead of `.is(":hover")`, try <strike>`!$(e.target).is('.myDiv')`</strike> `$(e.target).closest('.myDiv').length === 0` (`.closest` is used to detect if we are clicking the div or a child of the div).  I don't think IE7 or IE8 support the `:hover` CSS pseudo-property.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {                   
   if($(e.target).closest('.myDiv').length === 0) {
      alert("outside of blue div");
   }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/5/
More Tests: http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/8/
Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/14/

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the alert triggers if i klick on something inside of the div then. Here is an example (try klicking the text): http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/12/

Comment: @user263091: Change `if(!$(e.target).is('.myDiv')){` to `if ($(e.target).closest('.myDiv').length === 0){`  http://jsfiddle.net/uh8RB/14/